Mbufs iova-contiguous DPDK
I read packets from a NIC with DPDK into mbufs. My question is - is there a way that the mbufs I read will be IOVA-contiguous? When I iterate over the mbufs and print the iova address differences, I don't get a constant difference. Is there a possibility so the differences will be constant? (I use huge pages of 1G)
